# Customizing style with Shuffle.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, shuffle

I am using the library `Shuffle.js` and I need to change some styles for mobiles needs of my client. I need to change the position of the elements of `position:absolute` to `position:relative`.

My code is:

```
var Shuffle = window.shuffle;
var element = $( '#grid' );
var shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
    itemSelector: '.shuffleFeatured'
});

Shuffle.ShuffleItem.Css.INITIAL.position = 'relative';
Shuffle.ShuffleItem.Css.INITIAL.transform = 'inherit';
```

But it doesn't work, the styles are the same after that. Anyone could help to solve it? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use CSS media queries to detect the size of the screen. If the user is on a small screen, then use CSS to `position: relative`

Comment: Hi Jackson,

I tried to do it with CSS but when I filter the items they keep de `position:relative` and `transform:inherit` and then they don't show proplerly because the plugin can't recalculate their positions.